# Set x-ray of two objects inside another object

Tags: python, mesh, objects

I have a mesh 'Suzanne' parented to an armature 'Armature'. Both are located inside another mesh 'Cube'. I want both 'Suzanne' and it's armature 'Armature' to be visible in the 3D view through 'Cube'. I tried setting the x-ray of 'Suzanne' and it's armature 'Armature' to `True` in Python, but then 'Suzanne'only appears through 'Cube'. I wonder how I can make both 'Suzanne' and it's armature 'Armature' appear through 'Cube'.

The .blend file can be found here in this [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cz5l2lc94rqt0u7/xray.blend?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: Considering this is just for display anyways, could you get rid of the xray on Suzanne and instead add transparency to the cube?

Answer (score 0):

No. X-ray can't work that as as far as I know. Once you put both the armature and the monkey in x-ray, its like they are on the same "layer". The only way I can think of close to this is to invert the normals of the cube, but I don't think that meets what you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry, but inverting the normals didn't solve the problem

Comment: You also only want x-ray only on the armature.

Answer (score 0):

To see your armature, check *X-Ray* for the armature as shown below. Then set the *Maximum Draw Type* of the cube to *Wire* or *Bounds* depending on how much detail you want (wire gives more).

[image][image]

This is the result:

[image]